# How to set icon of the line edit in a QCombobox widget without inserting the item into the list?

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I want to set the icon on the left side of the QCombobox widget. I know I can insert a item first and then set the icon of the inserted item and then select this newly inserted item. However, I would like to do that without inserting a new item into the drop down list for special reasons. Windows ComboBox control allows us to change the icon of the edit box by using an index of -1. I don't know how to achieve that with QCombobox.

Thanks for any comments!

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it myself, but here is an idea.

QComboBox is based on Qt's model/view framework, so the items are contained into a **QStandardItemModel** which can be accessed with `QComboBox::model()`.

The steps would be:

- Instantiate a `QStandardItem`
- Use `setIcon()` and `setText()` on the QStandardItem (or use the proper ctor)
- When you want to add the item to the Combo list, append it thru the model.

Example:

```
QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(theIcon, theText);
[...]
QStandardItemModel* comboModel = qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(theCombo->model());
comboModel->appendRow(item);
```

Comment: The question was, how to set an icon _without_ appending an item to the model.